# How to forcefully disable this option "Request Desktop Website" in SFSafariViewController (iOS Swift 4.2)

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, swift4.2, sfsafariviewcontroller

I want to disable forcefully "Request Desktop Website" programmatically in SFSafariViewController.

All of my articles opening in the Website view by default. I want to open all my URLs in Mobile View.

I want to disable **Request Desktop Website** programmatically.

[image]